# Get data from adoquery to stringlist

Tags: delphi

Ok I have a query that should return all the issue numbers.  What I would like is to get each issue number that is returned and add it to a string list.

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
SQLQuery := 'SELECT issue FROM Comics WHERE SeriesName = '+Quotedstr(SeriesName)+' AND Volume = '+quotedstr(VolumeNumber);

ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(SQLQuery);
ADOQuery1.Active := true;
```

So once I got this , what is the best way to get the results into a string list. I have tried using `ADOQuery1.GetFieldList(issuelist,'issue');` but that wants a `tlist` not `tstringlist` not sure if that really matters or if I am even doing it right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to use GetFieldList. That returns a list of the field object in the dataset. You need to do something like this:

```
ADOQuery1.Open;
ADOQuery1.First;
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
begin
  issuelist.Add(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('issue').AsString);
  ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
```